# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, xml, unicode, encoding, python-unicode

I have this code:

```
    printinfo = title + "\t" + old_vendor_id + "\t" + apple_id + '\n'
    # Write file
    f.write (printinfo + '\n')
```

But I get this error when running it:

```
    f.write(printinfo + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It's having toruble writing out this:

```
Identité secrète (Abduction) [VF]
```

Any ideas please, not sure how to fix.

Cheers.

UPDATE:
This is the bulk of my code, so you can see what I am doing:

```
def runLookupEdit(self, event):
    newpath1 = pathindir + "/"
    errorFileOut = newpath1 + "REPORT.csv"
    f = open(errorFileOut, 'w')

global old_vendor_id

for old_vendor_id in vendorIdsIn.splitlines():
    writeErrorFile = 0
    from lxml import etree
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True) # makes pretty print work

    path1 = os.path.join(pathindir, old_vendor_id)
    path2 = path1 + ".itmsp"
    path3 = os.path.join(path2, 'metadata.xml')

    # Open and parse the xml file
    cantFindError = 0
    try:
        with open(path3): pass
    except IOError:
        cantFindError = 1
        errorMessage = old_vendor_id
        self.Error(errorMessage)
        break
    tree = etree.parse(path3, parser)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for element in tree.xpath('//video/title'):
        title = element.text
        while '\n' in title:
            title= title.replace('\n', ' ')
        while '\t' in title:
            title = title.replace('\t', ' ')
        while '  ' in title:
            title = title.replace('  ', ' ')
        title = title.strip()
        element.text = title
    print title

#########################################
######## REMOVE UNWANTED TAGS ########
#########################################

    # Remove the comment tags
    comments = tree.xpath('//comment()')
    q = 1
    for c in comments:
        p = c.getparent()
        if q == 3:
            apple_id = c.text
        p.remove(c)
        q = q+1

    apple_id = apple_id.split(':',1)[1]
    apple_id = apple_id.strip()
    printinfo = title + "\t" + old_vendor_id + "\t" + apple_id

    # Write file
    # f.write (printinfo + '\n')
    f.write(printinfo.encode('utf8') + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: If you look at the right side of the question, you will notice a column of "Related" questions. I suggest you start by looking at them. You would also have gotten a list of possibly duplicates when writing your question title.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you are right, as usual.  Comment erased.

Answer (score 73):

You need to encode Unicode explicitly before writing to a file, otherwise Python does it for you with the default ASCII codec.

Pick an encoding and stick with it:

```
f.write(printinfo.encode('utf8') + '\n')
```

or use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to create a file object that'll encode for you as you write to the file:

```
import io

f = io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

You may want to read:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

before continuing.

Comment: Using f.write(printinfo.encode('utf8') + '\n') works but creates odd characters Identit√© secr√®te (Abduction) [VF] which should be accented Identité secrète (Abduction) [VF]

Comment: @speedyrazor: please *do* read the links I provided. You are opening a UTF-8 file with something that displays the bytes as a different encoding instead. Pick the right encoding for your application.

Comment: @Martin Pieters: I have had a read through, but don't really understand. If I have "Identité secrète" in my XML file I am reading, I pick lines out and write them to a file, but that line comes out as "Identit√© secr√®te". Sorry to ask, but what code would sort this out please?

Comment: @speedyrazor: Your XML file uses a codec too. It either uses UTF-8 or has a different codec specified on the first line of the XML file. The XML parser then decodes that data to a Unicode value. When writing out the values to a file, you need to pick a codec again to write bytes. I picked UTF-8 for you because that codec can encode all of unicode, but whatever you used to view the resulting file used a **different** codec to interpret the bytes. The `é` character is unicode codepoint U+00E9. UTF-8 encodes that to two bytes, hex C3 and A9. Misinterpreting those two bytes gives you `√©`.

Comment: @speedyrazor: without knowing how you are *reading* the produces file again, I cannot help you further.

Comment: @speedyrazor: I didn't ask for how you produced the Unicode values, I asked how you were reading the file written by the script.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my original question to include the bulk of the code.

Comment: @speedyrazor: You still haven't told me how you are opening `REPORT.csv` after the script completes. You are reading that file somewhere and **there** you see `Identit√© secr√®te`. It is **that program** that is not interpreting the written data correctly. Your Python code is working as intended.

Comment: aahhh, penny finaly dropped. Open Office was incorrectly displaying those characters.

Comment: @speedyrazor: exactly. Excel is often worse for reading CSV encoded with anything other than the current locale setting. Imagine producing CSVs for a customer with a Norwegian codepage, who then share the same file with someone in Eastern Europe using a different Windows codepage.

Comment: I have the error message:
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9'
But this answer did not resolve the error

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza: there are lots of ways you can trigger that error message. The solution in this answer is addressed to the specific way the OP triggered it. E.g. if you are trying to write a Unicode string object to a Python 2 file object, you'll have to encode first.

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza: I'm sorry that it did not solve *your* problem, but you need to first determine if your problem is actually the same.

Comment: "You need to encode Unicode explicitly before writing to a file, otherwise Python does it for you with the default ASCII codec." that's the important bit I needed.

Comment: This solved my problem ,`# encoding=utf8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`