# Writing a simple query, getting a unicodeEncodeError, python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

The query:

```
query = "SELECT * from "+str(tablename)+" where user='"+str(user)+"' AND review_title='"+rt+"'"
```

The error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code:

```
rt = review_title.replace("'", "\\'")
rt = rt.replace('"', '\\"')
rt = unicode(rt).encode('utf-8')
query = "SELECT * from "+str(tablename)+" where user='"+str(user)+"' AND review_title='"+rt+"'"
```

In this case the tablename is `'ta_rest_review'`, the `user` is `'KANNONEPL...'` and `rt` is  `'Excelente pero \"OJO a la CUENTA\"'`

Comment: You have a `é` character somewhere in your values, but your sample input is missing that character.

Comment: When reporting on a Python problem, **always** include the traceback. If it is the actual `query` assignment, then that accented `é` character is in either the `user` or the `tablename` value.

Comment: In that case your problem with an `UnicodeEncodeError` is caused by calling `str()` on a `unicode` object with characters outside the valid ASCII range, an entirely different problem from the [post you commented on earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19833471).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* use string formatting to interpolate your data. Use SQL parameters instead!

Use the appropriate query parameter syntax for your database driver, it'll either use question marks or `%s` placeholders:

```
cursor.execute(
    'SELECT * from {0} WHERE user=%s AND review_title=%s'.format(tablename),
    (user, rt)
)
```

You'll still have to interpolate the tablename (make *absolutely sure* it is an existing table name, don't take user input to determine this!)

The database driver can then take care of escaping the `user` and `rt` values correctly for you, including encoding Unicode values to an encoding supported by the database.

Moreover, you avoid running the risk of a SQL injection security flaw if you try to 'escape' your database input yourself.

Look at your database driver documenation; the module should have a [`paramstyle` variable](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) that defines what style of parameter placeholder the driver supports, as well as explain if multiple styles are supported.

Comment: That worked, thanks for your answer.  Strange that I couldn't find it on here before.