# Cant encode ascii character u'\xe9'

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am getting a message `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9'` when I am writing a string to my file, heres how I am writing my file

```
my_file = open(output_path, "w")
my_file.write(output_string)
my_file.close()
```

I have been searching and found answers like this [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833440/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xe9-in-position-7) and the first one didn't work and then this one I'm confused why I am encoding data I want to be able to read

```
import io

f = io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. There's no such value as ASCII E9.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean? this is what I am getting as errors `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x96' in position 62393: ordinal not in range(128)` and `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 343071: ordinal not in range(128)` when I write my string to file

Comment: "Why I am encoding data I want to be able to read"—there is no text but encoded text.

Comment: @spenf10: Well yes, because that character isn't in ASCII. That's what I mean. The unicode character you're referring to is U+00E9. That isn't in ASCII, so trying to encode it in ASCII doesn't work. Use a different encoding. Note that to write text to a file, you *always* encode it - an encoding is just a mapping from text to binary data.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you're trying to write non-ASCII characters with the ASCII encoding. Since the built-in `open` function doesn't support the `encoding` parameter, then consider always using `io.open` in Python 2.7 (which is the default since Python 3.x).